# Microphone input routing from one to pcA to pcB and make call from pcB using Skype

Tags: remote-desktop

I connect to a computer remotely from my laptop using TeamViewer. Once connected to the computer, I use Skype (on that remote computer) to call a client. My issue is that I can hear the client on my headset connected to the laptop but the client can not hear my voice. Could you please advise me on the settings that should be made on TeamViewer (on laptop and remote computer)  and Skype settings (on remote computer and on the system of client) to make this communication work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a converence call in TeamViewer first to transmit your audio to the remote computer, then select that audio device as microphone.

I have not tested this so I don't know how exactly this works, but the only way to get audio to the remote is through this way.

That said, it is a lot easier to install skype on your pcA and bypass TeamViewer all together. Not only will TeamViewer introduce a lot of latency, it makes things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: LPChip Thanks for response.  Local conversion is working perfectly. but when I involve the team viewer that is mandatory to use. Actually I have pc at my home and other pc at office . I am using team viewer to connect the office pc. On the office pc Skype is installed from where I have to communicate with clients. If I make  a call using team viewer from home pc to office pc it's working fine but when I call from Skype I can hear what client speaks but client can not hear my voice as mentioned above

Comment: You need to use teamviewer conference call to transfer your local audio to the remote side. once it is there, you can setup skype to hear that audio. You may have to use the "what you hear" feature.